# How to display an array of 0 and 1, in a textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

in theory my matrix is formed, but I want to show it, as I show it; Is it correct to show it in a textview?, or in which I can show it.

My: "matrix [y] [x];"; only shows the last.

```
public void Matriz(){
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgviewREXBlancoNegro.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    int Width =  bitmap.getWidth();
    int Height  =  bitmap.getHeight();

    int matriz[][] = new int [Height][Width];

    for (int x=0 ; x<=Width-1; x++) {
        for (int y=0 ; y<=Height-1; y++) {
            int coordenada = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);// pixel
            double r = Color.red(coordenada);
            double g = Color.green(coordenada);
            double b = Color.blue(coordenada);
            double alpha = Color.alpha(coordenada);

            if (r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255 && alpha == 255) {
                 matriz[y][x]=0;
            }else{
                 matriz[y][x]=1;
            }
            txtviewmatriz.setText(matriz[y][x]+"");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to collect your output into a variable and set this value after your entire collection ends.

If you call the `setText()` method inside the loops, you override the content of the text field with each call. This is why you only see the last combination.

```
 String output = "";

 for (int x=0 ; x<=Width-1; x++) {
      for (int y=0 ; y<=Height-1; y++) {
          // your code
        
          output += matriz[y][x] + " ";
      }
 }

 txtviewmatriz.setText(output);
```